# Toast notification doesn't work in IOS but works in Android

Tags: ios, ionic2, toast, inappbrowser

Plugin :

```
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
```

Code:

```
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
constructor(private platform: Platform,private toast: Toast)){
    this.toast.show("Welcome!!", '5000', 'bottom').subscribe(
        toast => {
            console.log(toast);
        }
    );
}
```

This code is working on android but not on IOS , What could be the reason ? because it is not giving me any error also. 
**Note: This Toast notification is on InAppBrowser Page.**